# Following the Biur Halacha

Tags: halacha, minhag, halacha-theory, shulchan-aruch, commentaries

As far as I know, the most accepted Posek around the entire non-Chassidic Ashkenazi world is the Mishna Berura (and of course the Rama). He wrote the sections to his commentary to the Code of Jewish Law:

- Mishna Berura - concise and easy to learn additional laws and customs to the Shulhan Aruch as well as explanations usually bringing earlier sages such as: Elya Raba, Magen Avraham, and Baer Hetev.
- Biur Halacha - a little more in depth than the Mishna Berura where he usually sources his opinions and says why he holds like does
- Shaar HaTziyun - the sources for his words

Do the Ashkenazim that follow the M"B follow the words of the Biur Halacha as well? Or does this Hashkafa differ by Minhag?

Answer (score 5):

I can only speak from my experiences.  Those who the Mishna Berura as their halachic decisor of known cases will follow through on his psak in the Biur Halacha as well.